# what is the keys to minimise help frame of emacs

Tags: emacs, buffer, frame

I have a small screen, I typed ? in ediff mode and the control frame enlarges to show me the keybinding. How do I minimise it to its original size after that?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press <kbd>?</kbd> again. It's shown in the help, too:

> ? -help off